# Views slideshow with pagination

Tags: views, javascript

Basically i need to create slide show same like this one [example](http://www.dwell.com/).

In this slide show there should be pagination like (1,2,3,4) and i need text and picture should refer to another content type and this text must be taken from the content type(for example the first 100 characters.
How to achive this? what modules is best for this. any example will be nice.
I found some examples with views and slideshow module, but most problem is pagination and how to get the text from content type to show it on a slideshow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module and create a view with format Slideshow.

Check Readme file or Documentation of  the module to create a view.

Views Slideshow module uses [Jquery Cycle plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle) which enables you to create exact slideshow effect that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

add field row number
and uses this field in style: 
and set field to control

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step by step tutorial to create slideshow the way you want

http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-install-views-slideshow-module-on-drupal7

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [field_slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) module instead of "Views Slideshow"

> Compared to Views slideshows, building the slideshow from multiple nodes, this module builds it from a single node, with a multi-valued Image/Media/Field Collection field.